# SEC's API: Search for US GAAP Taxonomy Frames

Tags: accounting, xbrl, sec, gaap

Using the SEC's website, I'm looking for the XBRL frames for the `WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding` concept from the U.S. GAAP taxonomy.

Using this URL results in an error:

```
https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/frames/us-gaap/WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding/shares/CY2022Q1I.json
```

[The SEC's API documentation](https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation) provides [an example](https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/frames/us-gaap/AccountsPayableCurrent/USD/CY2019Q1I.json) of XBRL frames for current accounts payable using the U.S. GAAP taxonomy.

[The company facts for Microsoft Corp.](https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0000789019.json) shows this concept:

[image]

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to get XBRL frames for the `WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding` concept?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no data for that frame. There is data for a different frame though (Maybe that helps?): https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/frames/us-gaap/WeightedAverageNumberOfDilutedSharesOutstanding/shares/CY2021.json

Comment: This and also CY2022Q1 help though they're dated hence the instantaneous data (CY2022Q1I) are needed.  Is this delay possibly because the data aren't compiled yet?  Do you know the usual time lag between quarter-end and the instaneous data getting updated?

Comment: @Catalyx good question. I would guess so. There is only a hint on how to access the data most timely: https://www.sec.gov/os/webmaster-faq#fast-access . Alternatively, you could send this question to webmaster@sec.gov . Would be great if you could share your findings with the community.

Comment: The question has been posed to the site's webmaster since my comment to your answer.  I'll update this thread if there's any reply.